# How do you get the event parameter populated when connecting a lambda to an API Gateway (python 3)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API gateway resource set up with a GET method. It takes a URL Parameter (say ID). This method is set up with a lambda_proxy integration.

Reading the docs I thought that the event parameter in the lambda would be filled in with data from the request but the event object is being passed as empty. I confirmed this by logging event. I am testing using the test function in API Gateway.

Snippet from lambda code:

```
def my_handler(event, context):
  logging.error("event: " + event)

  ID = event["queryStringParameters"]["ID"]
```

The output in the cloudwatch logs is:

```
    [ERROR] 2020-11-18T17:19:24.859Z event:
    [ERROR] TypeError: string indices must be integers
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/lambda.py", line 63, in <module>
    my_handler("", "")
  File "/var/task/lambda.py", line 8, in my_handler
    devID = event["queryStringParameters"]["ID"]
```

[API Gateway Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl8HY.png)

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong with passing the parameter into the lambda?

Comment: How are you making the request to the API Gateway? Also, did you redeploy the API Gateway stage after setting up the integration?

Comment: Using the "test" button on API gateway and yes i redeployed (although I think using that button you don't need to deploy)